# CSS: Transition not working when changing a sibling on hover

Tags: hover, element, transition, siblings

I have two black boxes:
On hover, the whole background-color should change!

HTML:

```
<div id="trigger"></div>
<div id="trigger2"></div>
<div id="bg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
height: 100%;
}

#bg {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
widht: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 1;
background: #bbb;
}

#trigger {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -100px 0 0 -202px;
background: #333;
z-index: 2; 
}

#trigger:hover ~ #bg {
background: #EE0;
transition: .5s;
transition-delay: .2s;
}

#trigger2 {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -100px 0 0 2px;
background: #333;
z-index: 2;
}

#trigger2:hover ~ #bg {
background: #339;
transition: .5s;
transition-delay: .2s;
}
```

Here is my problem:

I want the background to keep its color until I hover to the other black box.

I tried to set a transition-parameter, so it keeps it color for ~1hour, but I cannot control this parameter!
Any transition-parameter set in the #trigger-section would take no effect. why is that so?

Instead of the black boxes and the colored background the three elements should get images, but this is a later challenge.

edit.

here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2v1p6scu/3/

thanks and kind regards!

Guenther

Answer (score 0):

ok i've found another script, which I could change for my behavior:

HTML:

```
    <div class="GMB-E"></div>
    <div class="GMB-M"></div>
    <div class="bg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.bg {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
right: 0px;
background-color: green;
z-index: 1;
transition: 2s ;
transition-delay: 999s;
}

.GMB-E {
position: fixed;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -100px 0 0 -202px;
background-color: red;
z-index: 2;
}

.GMB-E:hover ~ .bg { 
background-color: orange;
transition: 0.5s ;
}

.GMB-M {
position: fixed;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
margin: -100px 0 0 2px;
background-color: blue;
z-index: 2;

}
.GMB-M:hover ~ .bg { 
background-color: purple;
transition: 0.5s ;
}
```

now I try to replace the colors with images... ;)

greets!